# Ajax not responding on Node.Js Express server

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, docker

I'm using Express and running with Supervisor on a Docker container.

When making Ajax requests to the server it gets no response. I can navigate to the URLs Ajax is using and it responds. The rest of the application/site functions normally.

However, when  connecting and running the application manually, without using Supervisor, the Ajax requests work.

I initially thought it was a connection pool issue with concurrent connections but it's set to unlimited, same issue.

What's going on? The only thing that has changed is that the application is launched with Supervisor. Is there some hidden setting or configuration I don't know about?

***supervisor.conf***

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongod]
command=/usr/bin/mongod
stdout_logfile=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
priority=1
autorestart=true

[program:node]
command=node /opt/nodeapp/app.js
priority=2
autorestart=true
```

I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: The ajax call does not work, what does it return? any error? can you past here the response? with headers, if possible

Comment: It doesn't respond at all, it times out. But navigating to the URL in the browser works.

Comment: It could be that when you make a OPTIONS request (normally an ajax call is preceeded by this call) your server does not handle it?

Comment: OK but the Ajax works when launching the App myself, but not when using Supervisor to launch it. Would that change the server OPTIONS request response somehow?